# Determine the coeffiicients of a polynomial function

Tags: python

I get difficulty with coding the following:

Higher order derivatives.
a) Given n € N,   x0,a0,a1,…an € R with an != 0, write a program that determines

the coefficients A0,A1,….An of the unique polynomial function P of degree n that

satisfies the conditions
P(x0)= a0,  P’(x0)= a1,…….P(n)(x0)=an.

I know the math part very well but I stuck at the coding part. Please help!

Comment: Where did you get stuck with the coding. What have you tried?

Comment: Can you do it for the first derivative?

Comment: I reached to the conclusion that an = P°(n)(x)/n! -->An = an/n! and from here I could't calculate An-1 . Because I actually need the coefficients A0,A1,A2...,An not the this coefficients a0,a1,a2,...an

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this will work:

```
def poly(x0,*a):
    assert len(*a) > 0
    if len(*a) == 1:
        return [a[0]]
    return [a[0]] + [(j+1)*c for j, c in enumerate(poly(x0, *a[1:])]
```

what it does is that it throws the problem back to a similar problem. You can decide the derivative of the function by a similar problem with one coefficient less (the coefficients a1...aN). The case where you have only one coefficient is handled specifically to end the recursion formula.

The `[(j+1)*c for j, c in enumerate(poly(x0, *a[1:])]` construct will multiply each coefficient with one more than it's index, which means taking the anti-derivate of the polynomial.

Comment: I want to know wheter *a is a variable for all the coeficients, And have you used a list in which you put all the coeficients? And can I use this example for my code or should I rewrite it

Answer (score 1):

Now I managed to write a bit of code to determine the first derivative on a given degree. For example if n = 2, than P'(x0)= a1+ 2*a2*x0**1 -the first derivative, but I cannot manage to calculate from here the second derivative that should be : P''(x0)= 2*a2.
So here is my code so far:

def deriv(d1,n):
    for i in range(1,n+1):
        s+= a[i]* i*x0**(i-1)
        d1 = s
    return d1

Now I know that I would need to call the function deriv( d1) but I don't know how. I welcome any answers or suggestions